# Questions about the mechanics of a spinning CD.

Tags: physics, classical-mechanics

A CD is spinning counterclockwise with a radial velocity of $\omega=30\text{rad}/\sec$. The preface of what I did manage to solve and further details:
I was asked what is the period time (12 seconds), the frequency $({1\over 12})$. Then I was said there is **a point on the CD that is $15\text{cm}$ away from the center** and asked what it the linear velocity. I answered: $v={\pi\over 6}\cdot 15$. Radial acceleration: $a=-v\omega=-{\pi\over 6}\cdot 15\cdot 30\text{rad}$. Linear acceleration: $a=-15\cdot ({\pi\over 6})^2$.

The question I don't get is: As $t=0$, the **point** is pointing northward. When will it point north again? I am really clueless about that. If I am asked when it will be where it is again then the answer is 12 seconds, but if it refers to wind directions as quarters, then I am baffled. I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: Sounds as if the question is asking for "the time required to make one full turn". (Incidentally, $30$ radians is about five full turns ($2\pi$ radians is one full turn), a figure in general agreement with the hiccuping sound made by a skipping CD, so it's a good idea to double-check your calculations. :)

Comment: I really don't know what it has to do with my calculation, and I don't know how to fix them, because I am not familiar enough with the material. How can a part of a full turn be more than one full turn? 
I guess I have a misconception of what "turn" means.

Comment: Aren't 30 radians a $\pi\over 6$? i.e a $1\6$ turn?

Comment: @user86418 , isn't the question: what is the period time?

Comment: An angle of $30$ _degrees_ equals $\pi/6$ radians (a.k.a. $1/6$ of a turn). Perhaps the fundamental issue in your question comes down to [angle measurement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle#Units)? (I also read the question as "what is the period time?", but that's going to be about $1/5$ of a second.) :)

Comment: You are right. Thank you so far. I am still confused, though. If I am asked when the point will be where it is again, should I provide the period time as an answer? That's the time it takes for any point on the cd to be back where it was.

Comment: Yes, I read the question ("When will it point north again?") as asking for the period of rotation.